# Accessing folder in wpf app

Tags: wpf, path

I have a wpf app with this folder structure:

[image]

In the HomeController, I want to access the Images folder. I want to store an image in the Images folder from the HomeController. How can I do this? I tried using pack origin but it takes me to bin.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
pack://application:,,,/Images/image.png
```

Can be used in xaml or in code. For  more detailed explanation you can review [this Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about it.

In code: `Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/image.png");`

In xaml: `<element attribute="pack://application:,,,/Images/image.png"/>`